# Bind simple List<myClass> to Combobox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I would like to bind List of my class to CombpBox in WPF. I think it should be very simple.

I tried the code but it is not working:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        List<SimpleClass> ListData = new List<SimpleClass>();
        ListData.Add(new SimpleClass { Id = "1", Value = "One" });
        ListData.Add(new SimpleClass { Id = "2", Value = "Two" });
        ListData.Add(new SimpleClass { Id = "3", Value = "Three" });
        ListData.Add(new SimpleClass { Id = "4", Value = "Four" });
        ListData.Add(new SimpleClass { Id = "5", Value = "Five" });


        comboBox1.DataContext = ListData;
        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "{Binding Path=Value}";
        comboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "{Binding Path=Id}";


    }
}
public class SimpleClass
{
    public string Id;
    public string Value;
}
```

And the XAML is as follows

```
 <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="221,107,0,0" Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Both answers were correct submitted by Piotr Auguscik and blindmeis: comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
    comboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "Id"; And also the properties sould be changed: public class SimpleClass
{
    public string Id  { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
    comboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
```

In code behind you can't assign binding by setting string its a little bit more complicated. In this case `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` are expecting only property name, not the binding.

Comment: Yes, you were right. It should be just the names of the fields

Answer (score 1):

```
comboBox1.ItemsSource = ListData;
```

More info on the difference between DataContext and ItemsSource can be read [here](http://anyedotnet.blogspot.com/2008/11/datacontext-vs-itemssource.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding }" />
```

Comment: It can be written ItemsSource="{Binding}"

Answer (score 0):

It should be `comboBox.ItemsSource = ListData;`

Or in XAML

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListData}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                  SelectedValuePath="Id"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ListData}" />
```

Comment: That part with `SelectedValue` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can just bind to **public properties**, so your simpleclass is not right. and like  Piotr mentioned you have to set simple strings for Displaymemberpath.

working example

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<SimpleClass> ListData = new List<SimpleClass>();
        ListData.Add(new SimpleClass { Id = "1", Value = "One" });
        ListData.Add(new SimpleClass { Id = "2", Value = "Two" });
        ListData.Add(new SimpleClass { Id = "3", Value = "Three" });
        ListData.Add(new SimpleClass { Id = "4", Value = "Four" });
        ListData.Add(new SimpleClass { Id = "5", Value = "Five" });


        comboBox1.DataContext = ListData;
        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
        comboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
    }

public class SimpleClass
{
    public string Id  { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```